# Reformuler « a fait l’objet de beaucoup d’attention au cours des dernières années »

Tags: synonymes, reformulation

> La propagation des ondes acoustiques dans des matériaux poreux
>   hétérogènes **a fait l’objet de beaucoup d’attention au cours des
>   dernières années**.

Pour une présentation, je souhaite raccourcir cette phrase en reformulant la partie en caractères gras. Autrement dit, je souhaite la rendre plus « télégraphique ». Est-ce possible ?

Comment: Ça me semble difficile de réduire « faire l'objet d'attention », par contre tu peux enlever « au cours de » et remplacer par « ces », économie de 9 signes, c'est tout. Mettre « été » à la place de « fait », économie d'un signe.

Comment: Est-ce que : « a été très étudiée ces dernières années. » pourrait convenir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ces dernières années, la propagation des ondes acoustiques dans des matériaux poreux hétérogènes a suscité beaucoup d'intérêt.

Ces dernières années, on s'est beaucoup intéressé à la propagation des ondes acoustiques dans des matériaux poreux hétérogènes.

Depuis quelques années, on s'intéresse beaucoup à la propagation des ondes acoustiques dans des matériaux poreux hétérogènes.

Ces dernières années, la propagation des ondes acoustiques dans des matériaux poreux hétérogènes a retenu l'attention (des chercheurs).

Comment: Très bien «  a suscité beaucoup d'intérêt ».

Comment: Je te remercie pour toutes ces reformulations. La première est superbe !

Answer (score 1):

> La propagation des ondes acoustiques dans des matériaux poreux hétérogènes est un thème (très) en vogue.

Answer (score 0):

« **A été un souci majeur ces dernières années** » convient assez bien il me semble. On pourrait aussi dire «  **a été une préoccupation majeure ces dernières années** ».

Comment: Merci. *Souci : Importance attachée à quelque chose comme dans
Elle a le souci du travail bien fait. * Vous utilisez ce sens du mot. Est-il autant courant que l'autre sens (*Tracas, inquiétude comme dans Elle a beaucoup de soucis*) ?

Comment: @Dimitris Non, pas tout à fait ; je pense que c'est selon cette définition qu'il faut prendre « souci » :  « Personne, chose qui préoccupe, inquiète » ; l'inquiétude est possiblement un aspect négligeable c'est l'aspect consistant en de la  préoccupation qui prime. On pourrait d'ailleurs dire « une préoccupation majeure ces dernières années ».

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96890/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-reformuler--a-fait-lobjet-de-beaucoup-dattention).